# I recommend that [recommendation] be cleaned up and slowly burninated to death

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

> A recommendation engine tries to predict how much a user will enjoy certain goods (movies, books, songs...) and makes recommendations. They are often used by online vendors to suggest new purchases.

That'd be a great wiki excerpt, if the tag wasn't [recommendation](/questions/tagged/recommendation) instead of [recommendation-engine](/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine).

Of the **320** questions tagged [recommendation](/questions/tagged/recommendation), probably about a hundred should be tagged [recommendation-engine](/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine) instead.

A *lot* of the rest are questions asking for product/service recommendations or similar.  These questions should be closed with prejudice.

Please help by liberally applying closevotes to deserving questions, and improving & retagging the rest.  [There are currently **181** unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5brecommendation%5d%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0).

Comment: Better still: keep the tag, but use it as a flag, anything tagged with it in the future automatically gets put into the close vote review queue.

Comment: My delete button is all warmed up...

Comment: Also, I giggled at the [server] tag excerpt.

Comment: I'm seeing quite a few questions tagged with `recommendation` and `mahout`, it seems like these are attempting to refer to the [recommender](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation), do you think there should be a tag [mahout-recommender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mahout-recommender)?

Comment: @bluefeet, good catch.  Yeah, that looks like it could be a useful tag.

Comment: @Charles Cool, I already created it. I'll add those to the ones that need it. :)